# Need a batch file to find a string in a list, then launch a program if the string is found

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file that I need it to search for strings - if the string number is found, I need it to launch the same profile number, as the string number it found - the list is numbered 1-200 - I'm using this right now and it works, but is there a better way to do it?

Basically, if it finds "1" - launch Profile 1, if it finds 2, launch Profile 2 etc. I also don't need it to echo not found, but it doesn't work if I don't enter that, I do not know why because I don't understand how it works.

```
@echo off

>nul find "1" log.txt && (
  start /max "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"
) || (
  echo NOT found.
)

>nul find "2" log.txt && (
  start /max "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2"
) || (
  echo NOT found.
)
```

Also, in the above if there's a line that says "134" it will launch profile 1, profile 13, profile 34 and profile 134 instead of only just launching "134"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmmm... Suppose you have a groceries list to buy on the store. What do you usually do?

- Get a large list with *all* existent groceries, search each one in your buying list and if the grocery is found, buy it.
- Just buy the groceries that appears in the list.

If the second approach may also be used in your problem, then this is a suitable solution:

```
@echo off
for /F %%a in (log.txt) do start /max "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile %%a"
```

Note that you had *not* shown the format of your text file, so I assumed that it contain a number in each line, like this one:

```
1
2
134
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a timeout between launching all of them, as the script launches all of them at once. I tried using timeout /t but that did not matter.